# Read Data from Google Sheets into Pandas without the Google Sheets API

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I've got a spreadsheet URL like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1231SDFS3afer3SDfsdf-34SDFSDgfdsd42/edit#gid=5439787534

I tried this code I got a reference from https://towardsdatascience.com/read-data-from-google-sheets-into-pandas-without-the-google-sheets-api-5c468536550

```py
googleSheetId = '1231SDFS3afer3SDfsdf-34SDFSDgfdsd42'
worksheetName = 'abcde'

start_url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{googleSheetId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={worksheetName}"

url = start_url.replace(" ","")

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

but I am getting this error

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

How to resolve this without Google API authentication?

Comment: About `How to resolve this without Google API authentication?`, in your actual situation, is the Spreadsheet not publicly shared? And, you want to retrieve the values from the unshared Spreadsheet without authorization. Is my understanding correct? By the way, are you the owner of Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes the original spreadsheet is not publicly shared but I can view it and I want to access it without authentication. I also tried to do the same with the spreadsheet that I own but got the same error

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I also tried to do the same with the spreadsheet that I own but got the same error`, in your actual situation, you want to retrieve the values from a Google Spreadsheet which has other uses and is not publicly shared without the authorization. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot know the method for retrieving the values from a Google Spreadsheet which has other uses and is not publicly shared without authorization. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: If the sheet is not publicly shared, it does not matter if you can see it, you will need to use authentification

Answer (score 0):

The code provided works, with a sheet publicly shared ("Anyone on the Internet with the link can view").

The error you report is a pandas error generated during import, probably because of the shape/content of the data. It is not a google sheets error. Try downloading the data as csv and using read_csv on a local file - I predict you'll get the same error.